Adjust caption setup in talltblr environment
i have the following code, which produces a table with talltblr. However the caption layout does not correlate with the one used in my regular tables. There it looks like
Table 1  ..... (i guess with a quad spacing)
However, here it looks like:
Table 1: .....
How do i achieve this?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
    caption = {Captions}, 
    label = {example},
    ]{colsep  = 3.5pt,
      colspec = {@{} X[1cm,c] *{12}{Q[c,m]} @{}}, % Set first column width to 1 cm
      cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
      cell{1}{2} = {c=4}{},
      cell{1}{6} = {c=8}{}
    }
    \toprule 
    $m$ & Compact Model & & & & Benders Decomposition & & & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-13} 
    & LB & UB & {Gap\\ (\%)} & {Time\\ (s)} & LB & UB  & {Gap\\ (\%)} & {Time} & { \#\\ Iterations} & {Time\\ RMP (s)} & {Time \\ SP (s)} & {Time\\  IP (s)}  \\
    \midrule
1 & 10.0 & 15.0 & 25.4 & 100.0 & 12.0 & 13.0 & 1.6 & 37.9 & 10.0 & 0.7 & 3.2 & 1.0\\
2 & 20.4 & 32.7 & 20.4 & 200.0 & 25.0 & 27.8 & 1.0 & 44.7 & 15.0 & 1.3 & 4.3 & 0.1\\
3 & 30.9 & 45.6 & 17.8 & 300.0 & 33.8 & 36.4 & 0.9 & 64.9 & 20.0 & 2.3 & 6.6 & 1.0\\
4 & 40.0 & 60.0 & 30.9 & 400.0 & 50.7 & 52.8 & 1.1 & 57.6 & 25.0 & 2.7 & 5.0 & 0.8\\
5 & 50.8 & 80.9 & 24.5 & 500.0 & 61.8 & 65.4 & 0.9 & 82.0 & 30.0 & 2.1 & 8.7 & 0.2\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Your MWE (Minimal Work Examples) gives the same style of captions in talltblr as well as in other table float, since you use default caption style settings.
If you like to change default senttings, it is handy to load caption package and with its options determine captions styles. This styles you can use in talltblr by adding tblr-extras package. For example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{booktabs}  %   Loaded by TblrLibrary
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font={small, sf},
            labelfont=bf
            ]{caption}  % new
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs,
                caption}    % new
%\usepackage{amsmath}   %   Loaded by TblrLibrary
\usepackage{acronym}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

Here is caption int the float
\caption{test}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
    caption = {Captions}, 
    label = {example},
    ]{colsep  = 3.5pt,
      colspec = {@{} X[1cm,c] *{12}{Q[c,m]} @{}}, % Set first column width to 1 cm
      cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
      cell{1}{2} = {c=4}{},
      cell{1}{6} = {c=8}{}
    }
    \toprule 
    $m$ & Compact Model & & & & Benders Decomposition & & & & & & & \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-13} 
    & LB & UB & {Gap\\ (\%)} & {Time\\ (s)} & LB & UB  & {Gap\\ (\%)} & {Time} & { \#\\ Iterations} & {Time\\ RMP (s)} & {Time \\ SP (s)} & {Time\\  IP (s)}  \\
    \midrule
1 & 10.0 & 15.0 & 25.4 & 100.0 & 12.0 & 13.0 & 1.6 & 37.9 & 10.0 & 0.7 & 3.2 & 1.0\\
2 & 20.4 & 32.7 & 20.4 & 200.0 & 25.0 & 27.8 & 1.0 & 44.7 & 15.0 & 1.3 & 4.3 & 0.1\\
3 & 30.9 & 45.6 & 17.8 & 300.0 & 33.8 & 36.4 & 0.9 & 64.9 & 20.0 & 2.3 & 6.6 & 1.0\\
4 & 40.0 & 60.0 & 30.9 & 400.0 & 50.7 & 52.8 & 1.1 & 57.6 & 25.0 & 2.7 & 5.0 & 0.8\\
5 & 50.8 & 80.9 & 24.5 & 500.0 & 61.8 & 65.4 & 0.9 & 82.0 & 30.0 & 2.1 & 8.7 & 0.2\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Of course, you should/can define the caption style according to your wish (so far this is not done in your MWE). Given examples are just emphasize caption package capability.
BTW, be aware to order of package loading, also that some packages as booktabs correctly works in tabularray tables, they must be loaded as ˛tabularray libraries.
